# How to add a welcome message in the online code editor?

Tags: node.js, azure, bots, azure-qna-maker

I have created a Web App Bot (sdk3) in the Azure portal and am using Node.js. I have read the instructions for creating a welcome message [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-send-welcome-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp%2Ccsharpmulti%2Ccsharpwelcomeback).

However, I don't know where exactly to put the sample code copied from this page in the online editor.

I understand that I'm supposed to make changes in the `app.js` file, but where exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the sample code [`samples/javascript_nodejs/03.welcome-users`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/03.welcome-users) of Node.js in GitHub repo [`Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples).

The `bot.js` code is in the document you linked.